# ¿Como cargar datos de usuarios en referencias diferentes?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase, studio

Tengo un problema para la toma de datos (values) para diferentes usuarios que se encuentran en diferentes child.

Metodo para la toma de datos des Realtime Database:

```
private void getUserInfo(){
    String Id = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    if (DBref != null) {
        DBref.child("Admin").child(Id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    String name_tv = dataSnapshot.child("NOMBRE").getValue().toString();
                    String club_tv = dataSnapshot.child("CLUB").getValue().toString();

                    tv_club.setText(club_tv);
                    tv_nombre.setText(name_tv);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    } else {
        DBref.child("Entrenadores").child(Id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    String name_tv = dataSnapshot.child("NOMBRE").getValue().toString();
                    String club_tv = dataSnapshot.child("CLUB").getValue().toString();

                    tv_club.setText(club_tv);
                    tv_nombre.setText(name_tv);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

El primero metodo dentro del if funciona perfecto, el else no se executa. La idea es que tengo 2 clases de usuarios (admin y client), los tengo alojados en diferentes child para poder darles rules diferentes. La idea de esta funcion seria poder acceder con uno u otro y que me tome los datos para mostrar en el textview del activity de usuarios.

PD: Android Studio y Firebase (Realtime Database)

Comment: *La idea de esta funcion seria poder acceder con **uno u otro**...*  Ahí tienes la respuesta: ¿qué es lo que determina que los datos deben ser buscados en un child o en otro? En base a esa decisión, lanzarías la consulta dirigida al child específico,  ¿no?

Comment: cuando el user (sea admin o client) hace login, esta funcion deberia tomar los datos para que sean visualizados en el textview, mi problema surge en que nose como escribir el codigo. Los user admin estan en un child "admin" y los user client en otro child "client", debido a que tienen rules diferentes, me explico?. Soy muy nuevo en todo esto y no eh podido encontrar como resolverlo

Comment: Te lo pregunto de otro modo: ¿cómo determinas cuando el usuario es `admin` o es `client`?  Determinando eso, dirigirás la consulta al child específico.

Comment: Mmmmm los user admin estan en un child y los users client estan en otro, no hay un parametro que lo determine, solo la ubicacion diferente. Digo se supone que cuando un user ingresa a su cuenta (ingresa a su uid, donde sea que se encuentre) deberia tomar los values, pero no se como hacer para que la app determine cuando ingresa uno u otro, tal vez por eso "no funciona", no lo se